# Numerical formatting using String.Format

Tags: .net, formatting, numeric

Are there any codes that allow for numerical formatting of data when using string.format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loads, stick `string.Format` into Google :-)

A quite good tutorial is at [iduno](http://web.archive.org/web/20150303084355/http://idunno.org:80/archive/2004/07/14/122.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could format it this way:

```
string.Format("Format number to: {0 : #.00}", number);
string.Format("Format date to: {0 : MM/dd/yyyy}", date);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number. This  [MS site is probably the best place to look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another very good reference that compliments what Keith mentioned.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2547864/msnetformattingstrings

Answer (score 1):

As Keith said above. The most common one I use is currency:

```
String.Format("{0:c}", 12000);
```

Which would output £12,000.00